# How make double join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, user and transactions. In the transactions table, I would like to recover the pseudo associated with the id.

The table scheme :

```
transaction: id id_from id_to
user:        id pseudo
```

I would like to print :

```
ID PSEUDO_FROM PSEUDO_TO
```

Now, my sql query is:

```
SELECT *, t.id AS t_id
FROM transactions t LEFT JOIN user u ON t.t_from = u.id
WHERE (t.t_from=? OR t.t_to=?)
ORDER BY t.time DESC
```

But I have only `pseudo_from`.

Regards and thanks for help.

EDIT : I have adapt the query and it's work !

```
SELECT * , t.id AS t_id, u_from.pseudo AS from_pseudo, u_to.pseudo AS to_pseudo FROM transactions t LEFT JOIN user u_from ON t.t_from = u_from.id LEFT JOIN user u_to ON t.t_to = u_to.id (t.t_from=? OR t.t_to=?) ORDER BY t.time DESC
```

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la question... (I don't understand the question) Peut-etre la demander en Francais, et Anglais... il y a beaucoup de gens bilingues. (maybe ask the question in both French and English, lots of people are multilingual)

Comment: @wribit No! Why would you suggest such a thing? SO is in English.

Comment: @wribit: NO. This is an English-only site and we want all post be English only.

Comment: wow... so sorry. lol Even if he posts in both English and French... sounds exclusive to the max to me. The answer would be posted in both as well, for the OP's sake but also anyone who might have problems in English. I'll bring this up in MetaStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u_from.pseudo as from_pseudo,
       u_to.pseudo as to_pseudo,
FROM transactions t 
JOIN user u_from ON t.id_from = u_from.id
JOIN user u_to ON t.id_to = u_to.id
WHERE ? IN (t.id_from, t.id_to)
ORDER BY t.time DESC
```